# How do I make a function based create view in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a function based create view in django.

This is my model.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    content = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/content/")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/thumbnails/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='video_likes')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

This is my code in the views.py file.

```
def video_upload_view(request):
    form_class = VideoUploadForm 

    form = VideoUploadForm(request.POST) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.creator = request.user
            form.save()
            return reverse(home_page)

    return render(request, "video_upload.html", {"form": form })
```

This is my html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Upload{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class='btn btn-secondary'>Upload</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Video

class VideoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['content', 'thumbnail', 'title', 'description', 'is_public']
```

When I click upload the form refreshes and I don't get redirected neither anything uploads but when I look at the console there is a post request

```
"POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the `VideoUploadForm` to your question

Comment: Ok, I'll add it

Comment: Can you add the `Video` model too? The issue is probably that you are uploading files but have not added `enctype="multipart/form-data" ` to your form tag and passed `request.FILES` to the form in the view which is necessary when uploading files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading files as part of a form you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag so that the browser sends the files as part of the POST

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

When handling uploaded files you also need to pass the file data to the form

```
form = VideoUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

To alter the attributes of the object created from the form data you should first get the object using `form.save(commit=False)`

```
if form.is_valid():
    video = form.save(commit=False)
    video.creator = request.user
    video.save()
```

Comment: But now I get this error:
`IntegrityError at /upload/
NOT NULL constraint failed: base_video.creator_id`

Comment: You need to get the video using `form.save(commit=False)` first and then set the `creator` field on that object before saving. Added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

your button need `type="submit"` like this:

```
<button class='btn btn-secondary' type="submit">Upload</button>
```

and add the action in your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'APP_NAME:video_upload_view' %}>
```